# How to simulate try-finally or try-except in languages that don't have them

Tags: exception, lua, try-catch, try-finally

Is there **any** way to simulate a `try-finally` or `try-except` in a language that doesn't have them?

If there's some random, unpredictable, exception happens i need to be sure some cleanup runs.

i *could* try to be sure that no exception in thrown, that way i am sure my cleanup code always runs - but then i wouldn't need the `try-finally/except`.

Right this moment i'm trying to create a `try-finally` in Lua; but i think any solution would work in other languages as well.

Although, for the life of me, i cannot figure out how an exception can be handled without the plumbing provided by the language infrastructure.

But never hurts to ask.

Comment: Is the "assert" function not an option? http://www.lua.org/pil/8.3.html

Comment: @Will There's no problem with exceptions being thrown, either by me or *not* by me. i just need to stop them. Can `assert` do that?

Comment: Yes, I believe assert will prevent exceptions from being thrown and allow you to raise your own exception instead. Oh, and what Gerald posted is another good function too, pcall. I'm not too familiar with error handling in Lua, but I believe there are a few functions that'll do what you want.

Comment: @Will i read it as the opposite: "`assert(io.open(name, "r"));` *This is a typical Lua idiom: If io.open fails, assert will raise an error.*"

Comment: Ah, I think I am mistaken then, but my friends down in the answers section seem to have some good ideas :-)

Comment: Your wording is a little confusing; you're _really_ asking about Lua but you start out asking about languages in general (which is an amazingly tricky problem, really). It'd be cool if you edited your question to make it clearer that you're asking about how to do it with Lua only.

Comment: @DonalFellows i *assumed* any solution given in Lua would also work in other languages. Turns out i may be wrong - but i was hoping there some ancient secret to catching errors from the olden-times that has been lost to the mists of time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lua already has the necessary mechanisms to do something not entirely unlike exceptions. Namely `pcall`.

You can use `pcall` to execute any Lua function. If that function (or any function it calls) calls `error` (`assert` calls `error` if the assertion condition is not true), then flow control will return to the site of the `pcall` statement. The `pcall` will return false and an error message (what is passed to `error`).

With this, you can "throw" errors and "catch" them. Your "try" is just the `pcall`; your "catch" statement is what checks the `pcall` result.

Also, remember: Lua is a garbage collected environment. You shouldn't need to do any cleanup work. Or if you do, you need to change whatever Lua module requires it. Lua APIs should be Lua APIs, not C or C++ APIs.

Comment: In this case *"cleanup"* meant: `suppressFlag++;  pcall(doStuff); suppressFlag--;`. And it looks like my original fear was right - without language support catching arbitrary errors is not a possibility. But excellent work on finding `pcall`. i googled for about 5 minutes and couldn't find anything.

Comment: I know this answer is old, but I must say I disagree with your last paragraph. File handles, database connections, and all sorts of non-memory resources aren't garbage-collected. It's what `finally`-like constructs are for in other garbage collected languages.

Comment: What about Lua 4? It does not have a `pcall` function.

Comment: @posfan12: What about it? Lua 4 dates back to 2001, with Lua 5 coming out a scant 3 years later. It's too old to care about for most applications, and those where you have to use it will have to live within its limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Never programmed in lua (which is what you have this tagged as).  However, several web pages including this one http://jessewarden.com/2011/01/lua-for-actionscript-developers.html mentioned that protected call (pcall) is lua error handling device.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about this [Lua Exception Handling system](http://failboat.me/2010/lua-exception-handling/)? You can also use [Lua RAII](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ResourceAcquisitionIsInitialization) mechanisms.

Comment: Link is broken :(